# Connecting to a server on a different network controlled by a raspberry pi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, iptables, raspberry-pi

I didn't really know how to phrase this question, but this is my setup. I've got my Router and wirelessly I've got a raspberry pi connected to it. Then the pi tunnels the connection from the wifi to the ethernet so that I can connect devices through the ethernet on a switch. So how can I either A get a server that connects to that switch and access it from my computer, or B get devices on that switch to access a server that's on my main network.

[image: My Network]

If I SSH into the Raspberry Pi, I can ping both my 192.168.0.* and 192.168.1.*
but I cannot ping 192.168.1.* from my PC. However if I SSH into the Raspberry Pi, then SSH from there into the Pi Server I can actually ping my local machine at 192.168.0.3.

So how can I get it so I can access a webserver running on the Pi Server from my PC? Or better yet, have network traffic be communicated from my Server to my Xbox?

I really hope I'm explaining it well enough, cause I'm having a horrible time figuring this out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `tunnels the connection from the wifi to the ethernet`. Sounds more like you just want the pi to be the router (gateway) of `192.168.0.0/24` for `192.168.1.0/24` (and that of `192.168.1.0/24` for `192.168.0.0/24`). You really just need to enable IP forwarding on the pi and add the aforementioned routes to the default gateway of the two subnets respectively.

Comment: I mis-spoke what I meant was tether. The Pi is running LibreElec and connected to my main network via WIFI. The Ethernet wasn't being used so I wanted to find a way to use it to connect the devices near my TV that don't have WiFi. So I followed a guide to get the Ethernet tethered to the WiFi so that I can share the WIFI connection with my Ethernet devices. Unfortunately my Modem/Router doesn't seem to have IP Forwarding. It's an ARRIS TG3452A. I haven't really been able to understand IP Routes yet, if there are specific directions they'd really help out.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently what you mean by "tunnels the connection" is to allow the networks that the two interfaces of the Pi connected to to be able to communicate with each other via the Pi, which means you want to make the Pi a router/gateway.

To do so, you enable IP forwarding on it:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To make the setting persistent, do:

```
echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Or if you manage the interfaces with systemd-networkd, your can add `IPForward=ipv4` to any of the `.network` files instead.

Unless you have firewall (e.g. iptables) rules on the Pi that limit all/certain forwarding traffics, traffics from any of the interfaces will be forwarded to another according to the routes.

If the Pi is not the default gateway of the `192.168.1.0/24` hosts (Xbox, Pi Server) yet, make it so, either by pushing itself as that with DHCP, or set it manually on the hosts. For example:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

This should cover both `192.168.0.0/24` (unless you have another route for that) and the Internet.

Then you would need to add a "return route" on `192.168.0.1` (i.e. make `192.168.0.48` the gateway for `192.168.1.0/24`. Again, `/24` is assumed). For example:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.48
```

Likely you would be adding the (static) route on some web admin UI. So just fill in `192.168.1.0`(`/24`) as the destination, `255.255.255.0` as the subnet mask if it doesn't take a prefix length, `192.168.0.48` as the gateway. Add it as a LAN side route (instead of WAN/Internet side).

If the gateway/router is so lame that it doesn't allow you to add a static route by any means, you will need to do IP masquerading on the Pi with a iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Or, preferably:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.48
```

If the WiFi IP of the Pi doesn't change over time (i.e. static).

Now traffics from `192.168.1.0/24` would appear to be originated from the Pi to the gateway (and the `192.168.0.0/24` hosts), therefore their replies will be reaching the source host via `192.168.0.48` without a return route. The downside of this is that, since your are adding another layer of NAT/PAT, certain applications might not work through the "tether".